# What to choose for the distribution of $x$ to estimate $f(x)$ as linear

Tags: normal-distribution, uniform-distribution, estimation

I have to estimate $y = f(x)$ as a linear function of $x$ on a given range.

I can measure $y$ for as many $x$ values as I want. Each measure has its own measurement error. Assuming this error is random.

How should I choose the distribution of the $x$?
Normal distribution? Uniform distribution?

My guess is that with Uniform distribution, the measures of $y$ for the $x$ close to both edges of the range will have more weight than the ones in the middle.

That's why I'm guessing normal distribution of $x$ should be better.

Is that true?

Any pointers to literature on this matter?

Comment: You are not too clear want you want to achieve but I guess you want at least these two things . 1) To be sure that it is a linear relationship in which case you want a spread over all $x$ in the range. 2) To estimate the slope of the line in which case points near the end of the range will give the best estimate.  To see this imagine if you were only allowed two measurements, you would not take two near the centre of the range.

Comment: @user121049 I'm sure the relation is linear, by design. That's for electronic stuff designed by co-workers. I do want to estimate the slope and intercept. I'm used to make two measurements close to the edge of the $x$ range, and estimating from these. I was wondering if by making more measurements î'd have more precise fit. But where to measure?

Comment: The error in the measurement of the slope goes roughly as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $n$ is the number of measurements. So many measurements is good. I would make them evenly across the range, perhaps favouring the edge of the range if you are only doing a few measurements. See here for a formulae giving the error in the slope https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Normality_assumption.